# How to find the web element of a field whose locator is dynamically changing in each page

Tags: selenium, webdriver, dynamically-generated

How to find the web element of a field whose locator is dynamically changing in each page?

```
<span id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gv‌​DynamicControlsCol1_‌​ctl00_ctl22_txtLabel‌​" class="aspNetDisabled">TextBox_Col1_201609150233466412</span‌​> 

    On second page:

        <a id="WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvCol1St‌​ep2_lnkControlLabel_‌​9" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHol‌​derBody$wzWorkflowCo‌​nfig$gvCol1Step2$ctl‌​11$lnkControlLabel',‌​'')">TextBox_Col1_20‌​1609150233466412</a>

    `Xpath` of the web element in the first page:

        //*[@id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl22_txtLabel"]

    `Xpath` of the web element in the next page:

        //*[@id="WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvCol1Step2_lnkControlLabel_9"]
```

HTML in the First Page

```
    <span id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl24_txtLabel" class="aspNetDisabled">TextBox_Col1_201609150233466412</span>

    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody$wzWorkflowConfig$gvDynamicControlsCol1$ctl00$ctl24$hdnSeq" id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl24_hdnSeq">

    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody$wzWorkflowConfig$gvDynamicControlsCol1$ctl00$ctl24$ColValue" id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl24_ColValue" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody$wzWorkflowConfig$gvDynamicControlsCol1$ctl00$ctl24$hdnMandatory" id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl24_hdnMandatory" value="False">

    </td><td style="width:40%;">
    <input name="ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody$wzWorkflowConfig$gvDynamicControlsCol1$ctl00$ctl24$txt" type="text" id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl24_txt">

    </td><td style="width:10%;">
    <a id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl24_lnkB" title="Delete" class="radGridDelete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody$wzWorkflowConfig$gvDynamicControlsCol1$ctl00$ctl24$lnkB','')">Delete</a>

    </td>
    </tr>
```

HTML source on Second page for the same field

```
<tr>
    <td class="Shorter" style="width:29%;">
    <a id="WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvCol1Step2_lnkControlLabel_10" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody$wzWorkflowConfig$gvCol1Step2$ctl12$lnkControlLabel','')">TextBox_Col1_201609150233466412</a>
    </td><td style="width:30%;">
    <input name="ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody$wzWorkflowConfig$gvCol1Step2$ctl12$txt" type="text" id="WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvCol1Step2_txt_10" style="width:90%;">
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Share `HTML` for element on both pages

Comment: Text Box Element in the First page                                                                          

<span id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl22_txtLabel" class="aspNetDisabled">TextBox_Col1_201609150233466412</span>

Same Element in the next page

<a id="WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvCol1Step2_lnkControlLabel_9" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody$wzWorkflowConfig$gvCol1Step2$ctl11$lnkControlLabel','')">TextBox_Col1_201609150233466412</a>

Comment: @AutomationEnthusiast Use Contains and text for both pages 'For the first page

//span[contains(text(),'TextBox_Col1_')]

for the second page

//a[contains(text(),'TextBox_Col1_')]'

Comment: Throughout this page, all the text boxes ids starts with 'TextBox_Col1_'...

Answer (score 0):

You could find some fixed part of your id and use it to find targeted element.
For example, if you have `id=123456something1243`, and this "something" part is always there, you could find it with `.//*[contains(@id,'something')]`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion....                                                                                                    But here, " //*[@id="WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gv " is common for all the control fields in this page. There is no fixed part in above ids where I can use [contains(@....)]

Comment: Maybe there is some text or something? Provide html source so maybe we could help.

Comment: Text Box Element in the First page


<span id="ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl22_txtLabel" class="aspNetDisabled">TextBox_Col1_201609150233466412</span>

Same Element in the next page


<a id="WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvCol1Step2_lnkControlLabel_9" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody$wzWorkflowConfig$gvCol1Step2$ctl11$lnkControlLabel','')">TextBox_Col1_201609150233466412</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can try below `XPath` to match both elements:

```
//*[text()="TextBox_Col1_20‌​1609150233466412"]
```

or, if numerical part could dynamically change:

```
//*[starts-with(text(), "TextBox_Col1_")]
```

Comment: In this through out the page, all the text boxes starts as "TextBox_Col1_"

Comment: Ok. so use first option with exact text

Comment: Date (20‌​160915) is embedded with this Id " TextBox_Col1_20‌​1609150233466412 " - Could not identify ' 0233466412 ' what is it ?

Comment: Is this an exception you get with my `XPath`?

Comment: This seem to be date+some entry index. Is it always constant for mentioned element?

Comment: No, it is changing each time.

Comment: Does this `//*[starts-with(text(), "TextBox_Col1_20‌​160915")]` works?

Comment: Actually, we are dragging and dropping the objects (control fields such as text box, radio button, drop down,etc...) Each time when we drag objects and drop (for example : text box) , it creates the id as 'TextBox_Col1_<Date+unique random id>'. So, if I drag & drop two or more fields on same date(TextBox_Col1_20160915), all the fields would have same ids  "TextBox_Col1_20‌​160915"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `cssselecter` instead of `xpath` if some of your id attribute content matching -

```
[id*='WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig']
```

Comment: But in next page, css selector is different for the same field

Comment: above mentioned css selector is partial match. Have you tried this for next page to ?

Comment: yes, tried it .. #ctl00_WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvDynamicControlsCol1_ctl00_ctl22_txtLabel                                                CSS Selector in Next page
#WorkflowContentPlaceHolderBody_wzWorkflowConfig_gvCol1Step2_lnkControlLabel_9

Answer (score 0):

Use Contains and text for both pages 'For the first page

```
//span[contains(text(),'TextBox_Col1_')]
```

for the second page

```
//a[contains(text(),'TextBox_Col1_')]
```